# Google authentication, get the accestoken and the idtoken

Tags: react-native, google-oauth

As i can get the access token and idtoken at the same time, i find that the only way to get the id token is responseType: "id_token", but this way it doesn't return me the access token. However if I remove in responseType: "id_token", it only returns the access token and not the id token.

```
const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useAuthRequest({
    expoClientId:
      "xxxx",
    iosClientId:
      "xxxx",
    androidClientId:
      "xxxx",
    webClientId:
      "xxxx",
    responseType: "id_token",
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify multiple response types using a space delimited list.

Ex:  responseType: "id_token token"

Comment: I tried it, but i get this error, Parameter not allowed for this message type: code_challenge_method

Comment: I wasn't sure which OAuth flow you were using here.   That error message sounds like you are using the authorization code flow with PKCE.  Try responseType: "id_token code"

Comment: I try but don't work id_token code"